# C# Azure Cosmos DB - How to select large amount of data (~100,000 documents)

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have a Cosmos DB which I need to query 100 000 individual documents, using C#. This will be to populate a grid (with paging obviously). I have done a lot of searching but only seem to find the use of a FeedIterator to query data.

Currently I'm using this code to query my test data:

```
using (var appsIterator = _container.GetItemQueryIterator<SensorMaster>(query))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t\tID\tName\tUnitID\tPoints");
            while (appsIterator.HasMoreResults)
            {
                var apps = await appsIterator.ReadNextAsync();
                foreach (var item in apps)
                {
                    count++;
                    Console.WriteLine($"{item.ID}\t{item.Name}\t{item.UnitID}\t{item.Points}");
                }
                charge += apps.RequestCharge;
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Total charge: {charge}");
        }
```

This selects ~3900 records but takes around 45 seconds to do this.
Is there a better way to select a large number of documents/records?

Comment: You should start with the Cosmos DB documents. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-getting-started

Comment: @nullforce, thank you. Could you please give a bit more detail? Does this mean using DocumentClient instead of CosmosClient?

Comment: If I remember correctly, when creating the query, you can define a MaxPageSize. By setting this to a meaningful size (e.g. 1000) you get back the first thousand elements and a continuation token. Then you can create the same query again and add your token, returning the next 1000 elements. I think, this should work better. Also check your RU consumption and allowed max value. Maybe you are throttled.

Comment: @Brydon You can use `CosmosClient` like in their samples: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cosmos-db-sql-api-dotnet-samples/blob/v3/300-query-items/Program.cs

Comment: Do you have the Ids and PartitionKey values of the documents you want to read?

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta all the IDs are GUIDs and the partition is done on the ID

Comment: But do you know those values? Do you know the IDs you want to read? If yes, you can use Container.ReadMany

Answer (score 2):

For very large queries where you want to page the results, use the continuation token. You can get more information and learn how to use here, [Pagination in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-pagination).

It is MaxItemCount you want to focus on, not MaxPageSize.

As an aside, paging 100K records to a user is a strange use-case. I don't think I can recall a time where someone wanted to scroll through 100K items.

Comment: Thanks Mark. So what I have is a SQL DB with a master table and a child table, each master table record has ~300 child records associated. This is then queried in a grid on a portal. What I'm doing is migrating this to Cosmos.

Comment: Ok, still don't understand though why you'd want to run a query to page through 100K results.